# How to pass Id of a div that is clicked to a function that handles the click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I want to my div ids to correspond to items in a database. Based on an id my app will pull appropriate content from a database.

Hence when I use .click() to handle a click I need to pass the Id of the div being clicked to the function that handles it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `click` event handler function, the context (the `this` keyword) refers to the DOM element that triggered the event, you can get the id from it, for example:

```
$('div[id]').click(function () { // all divs that have an id attribute
  var id = this.id; // or $(this).attr('id');

  someOtherFunction(id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a `click` handler `this` corresponds to the DOM element which was clicked. You can use it to extract the `id`:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    // Get the id of the clicked div
    var id = this.id;
    // Do something with it ...
});
```